# Cloning a repository into an already existing directory

Tags: git, github, directory, access-token, git-commit

I can’t commit or push anything to my GitHub because my token has expired and when I try to clone the repo again with the new access token it says that the directory already exists and is not empty..

So how do I continue to work on the directory using the new token? Do I need to clone the repo again or there’s other ways to go about it?

I tried cloning the repo again and it said the directory already exists and isn’t empty and when I commit it says the directory is untracked

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your repo to point to the origin with the updated token. The easiest way to update it is with the cli.

You can check your current origin with:

```
git remote -v
```

This should display the origin url with the outdated token.

**To Update your token:**

Remove your current, expired, remote URL by running:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Now add a new remote with your updated GitHub personal access token:

```
git remote add origin https://[PERSONALACCESSTOKEN]@github.com/[USERNAME]/[REPO].git
```

Comment: Why remove the remote and then re-add it when it's possible to simply change it? On the other hand — what if the token is not stored in the URL but in a credential cache?

Comment: Deleting it first is more of a preference. `git remote set-url origin` can be used to overwrite it in one command. For this answer I assuming the minimum of git only being installed on the machine. But using a [credential cache](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) would be better.